# SQL - Finding different names with the same values

Tags: sql, sqlplus

For example,

In a 'Car' table you have 'Ferrari' appearing 4 times. And 'Lamborghini' and 'Ford' appearing 4 times to.

How do you make, via SQL, a command that shows all the cars in 'Car' that have the same value/amount as Ferrari ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by value/amount? the number of times it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select brand from car
group by brand
having count(*) = (select count(*) from car where brand = 'Ferrari')
```

ok, too slow... that's for the boss comming in :-)

Comment: I'm glad it did, but Li0liQ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8743058/1127872) was quicker with the exact same answer, so the accept should probably go to him to be fair

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    Name
FROM
    Cars
GROUP BY
    Name
HAVING
    Count(Name) = (
    SELECT
        Count(*)
    FROM
        Cars
    WHERE
        Name = "Ferrari"
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
with a as
(
select make, count(*) tot from car
group by make
)
select * from a where a.tot = (select tot from a where make='Ferrari');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(make) FROM Car WHERE make = 'Ferrari'
```